# Java EE method to replace dollar sign ($) variables with custom string

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee

Is there a pre-written method to replace dollar-sign name variables in a string with a predefined constant?

For example, the following code :

```
Map<String, Object> myVars = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
String str = "The current year is ${currentYear}.";
myVars.put("currentYear", "2014");
System.out.println(Replacer.replaceVars(str, myVars));
```

... would have this output:

```
The current year is 2014.
```

Comment: you could always use the replace method of string with a regex expression.. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does this too if you need to support more advanced use cases.  I was able to utilize code from the following class for my use cases.  See the `parseStringValue` method.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java

In your case, you need to pass in a `PlaceholderResolver` that uses your `Map` to resolve the placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any standard Java class which would support this behaviour but writing your tool wouldn't be so hard. Here is example of such solution:

```
class Replacer {
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(?<key>[^}]*)\\}");

    public static String replaceVars(String format, Map<String, ?> map) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(format);
        while (m.find()) {
            String key = m.group("key");
            if (map.containsKey(key)) {//replace if founded key exists in map
                m.appendReplacement(sb, map.get(key).toString());
            } else {//do not replace, or to be precise replace with same value
                m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group());
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

We could take advantage of default method [`getOrDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) introduced in Java 8 to Map interface and replace

```
while (m.find()) {
    String key = m.group("key");
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {//replace if founded key exists in map
        m.appendReplacement(sb, map.get(key).toString());
    } else {//do not replace, or to be precise replace with same value
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group());
    }
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

with

```
while (m.find()) 
    m.appendReplacement(sb, map.getOrDefault(m.group("key"), m.group()));
m.appendTail(sb);
```

But to be able to use this method we first would need to specify type of value in map - in other words we would need to change type of accepted Map from `Map<String, ?> map` to type like `Map<String, String> map`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class. Your example would look like this:

```
int currentYear = 2014;
String str = "The current year is {0}.";
str = MessageFormat.format(str, currentYear);
```

This is probably the best version, but you could always use a regex as well:

```
public String format (String input, Map<String, String> replacement)
{
    for (String key : replacement.keySet())
        input = input.replaceAll("\\${"+replacement+"}", replacement.get(key));
    return input;
}
```

Comment: MessageFormat doesn't support `${}` convention, or any mapping. Also your second approach is error-prone: what if OP would want to replace `${foo}` with `${bar}` and `${bar}` with ${foo}`?

Comment: @Pshemo The OP didn't say that he can only use `${foo}` (for the first one he need `{0}` of course), and if he want to he can use my second solution

Comment: This question is about *dollar-sign name variables* as OP specified in his question. Also as explained in previous comment solution based on replacing each first key-value pair, then second key-value pair can cause problems. Lets say that our string looks like `hello ${key1} ${key2} ${key3} ...` which contains more of `key1`, `key2` and `key3`, and for some reason we want to change their order so now `key1->key2` `key2->key3` and `key3->key1`. With your approach we will end up with `key1` being everywhere (`key1` will become `key2` which will become `key3` which finally will become `key1`).